# como resolver o problema Task 'scripts' is not in your gulpfile

Tags: gulpfile

este é meu gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');

// task para o sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('sass/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

// tasks para JavaScript
// task para babel
gulp.task('babel', () =>
    gulp.src('scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['env']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
);
// task minify
gulp.task('compress', function() {
  gulp.src('scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(minify({
        ext:{
            src:'.js',
            min:'-min.js'
        },
        exclude: ['tasks'],
        ignoreFiles: ['.combo.js', '-min.js']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
});

// scripts
// gulp.task('scripts',function(){
//     return('/scripts/**/*js')
//     .pipe(babel('babel'))
//     .pipe(minify('compress'))
// });

// task para watch
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
// task default gulp
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch', 'babel', 'compress']);
```

O bloco scripts não existia originalmente até quando eu tento salvar meus scripts para minifica-los e toda vez o gulp trava com essa mensagem de erro ai tentei escrever a task mais agora quando removo o comentario para executar e tentar minificar o erro é diferente segue abaixo o erro.

> at Gulp. (/home/rafaelejosi/Área de
>   Trabalho/projetos/gulpfile.js:40:6) 
>   at module.exports (/home/rafaelejosi/Área de
>   Trabalho/projetos/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/rafaelejosi/Área de
>   Trabalho/projetos/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/rafaelejosi/Área de
>   Trabalho/projetos/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/rafaelejosi/Área de
>   Trabalho/projetos/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
>   at Gulp. (/home/rafaelejosi/Área de
>   Trabalho/projetos/node_modules/gulp/index.js:36:18)
>   at Gaze. (/home/rafaelejosi/Área de
>   Trabalho/projetos/node_modules/glob-watcher/index.js:18:14)
>   at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>   at Gaze.emit (events.js:172:7)
>   at Gaze.emit (/home/rafaelejosi/Área de
>   Trabalho/projetos/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:129:32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

percebi o erro no meu próprio código está em uma chamada do watch

```
 // task para watch gulp.task('watch', function(){ gulp.watch('sass//.sass', ['sass']); gulp.watch('scripts//.js', ['scripts']); });
```

Alterei a palavra scripts por babel que é outra task do meu código e resolvi o problema

```
 // task para watch gulp.task('watch', function(){ gulp.watch('sass//.sass', ['sass']); gulp.watch('scripts//.js', ['babel']); });
```